# php base64_encode hash_hmac and java gives different results

Tags: java, php, encoding, base64, sha256

I saw some same questions in stack-overflow but it doesn't help me.

I have this php code

```
$signature=base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", trim($xmlReq), $signature_key, True));
```

I want to write java equivalent to that and this is my java code.

```
public static String encodeXML(String key, String data) {
    String result = "";
    try {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(secretKeySpec);
        result = Base64.encodeBase64String(mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        log.error("exception occured when encording HmacSHA256 hash");
    }
    return result;
}
```

but they give different results. 
someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Commons Codec

```
 import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
 ....
 Base64.encodeBase64String(.....);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP Test Code:

```
 $signature=base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", 'Message', 'secret', true));
 echo $signature;
```

Java Test Code:

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import java.util.Base64;
public class TestJava {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         String secret = "secret";
         String message = "Message";

         Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
         SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
         sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

         Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
         String hash = encoder.encodeToString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
         System.out.println(hash);
     } catch (Exception e){
       System.out.println("Error");
     }
  }
}
```

Output for both should be:
     qnR8UCqJggD55PohusaBNviGoOJ67HC6Btry4qXLVZc=

Comment: Base64.Encoder is in java 8. How to do this using java 7?