# Hash computed on php doesn't match one in java

Tags: java, php, hash, hmac, sha512

I'm trying to send requests to API. Api docs provide examples for salt and sign that should be present in request body.
PHP example:

```
$sign_key = 'testString';  
$salt = sha1('testKey');  
$sign = hash_hmac('sha512', $salt, $sign_key);
```

My java code is:

```
String salt = DigestUtils.sha1Hex("testKey");  
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(salt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), 
 "HmacSHA512");  
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA512");  
mac.init(secretKeySpec);  
String sign = Hex.encodeHexString(mac.doFinal("testString".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

Salt calculated on php and java matches, but sign differ.
I've checked some posts like following:
[Java HmacSHA512](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843682/java-hmacsha512)
[php base64_encode hash_hmac and java gives different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950993/php-base64-encode-hash-hmac-and-java-gives-different-results)
[Compute HMAC-SHA512 with secret key in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355241/compute-hmac-sha512-with-secret-key-in-java)
Yet nothing seems to work. I'm pretty confused about this, and would be glad if anybody could explain to me, what am i missing.

Comment: Title implies mismatch of hash generated in two PHP instances but body indicates it is PHP and Java.  Clean up the title?

Comment: renamed the title

Comment: I assume Java `sha1Hex("testKey")` produces a hex-encoded string representing the bytes, whereas PHP `sha1('testKey')` produces the actual bytes themselves. The solution would be don't use sha1Hex, instead in Java compute `byte [] salt = sha1("testKey")`.

Comment: sha1Hex is used for salt, and salt are equal on php and java (both as hexString and byte array). The issue is with mac behaviour itself.

Comment: I see that php `sha1()` returns the hex-encoded value, so `sha1Hex("testKey")` does in fact produce the same output in Java. The problem is simply that you have the arguments reversed. If you instead compute `hash_hmac('sha512', $sign_key, $salt);` you get the same output as Java. Or maybe you meant to reverse the arguments on the Java side? The use of a variable called salt involving a string called `testKey` and a variable called signKey involving a string called `testString` make it impossible to guess which you intend to be the hmac key and which you intend to be the data.

Comment: Oh god. Now i feel dumb. Indeed i reversed args in java and hashes match each other. Thanks!